# Cannot read property push of undefined while trying to push field value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently code is as given below,

```
var child_tids = [];
      $('.term-selection').each(function(index){
        var field = $(this).attr('field');
        child_tids.push($(this).val());
      });
```

I need to segregate it based on the attribute 'field'
So I tried the below

```
var child_tids = [];
          $('.term-selection').each(function(index){
            var field = $(this).attr('field');
            child_tids[field].push($(this).val());
          });
```

But it gives me the error in console "Cannot Read property push of undefined, how can I implement it?

Comment: Use an object, not an array.  Arrays are indexed by numbers.  The use case you are trying to do, appears to be trying to use a string key to identify the value.  `var child_tids = {};  child_tids[field] = value`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`child_tids` would need to be an object, and then create an array for each field you can try:

```
var child_tids = {};
$('.term-selection').each(function(index){
   var field = $(this).attr('field');
   if (!child_tids[field]) child_tids[field] = [];
   child_tids[field].push($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Is it okay if I add some syntactic sugar to your answer? `:P`

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an object and not an array. Use something like:

```js
var child_tids = {};
$('.term-selection').each(function(index) {
  var field = $(this).attr('field');
  if (typeof child_tids[field] != "object") child_tids[field] = [];
  child_tids[field].push($(this).val());
});
```